.NET/SQLite on Ubuntu - libe_sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
My website has been working perfectly fine on Ubuntu for a long time. After simply updating packages from 8.0.2 to 8.0.4 and re-publishing again, now I get an error that it can't load libe_sqlite3.so. How can I get the website back online?
I tried adding the SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 package but that didn't help.
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception.
 ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'e_sqlite3' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you
/var/www/store.spiritualselftransformation.com/e_sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/e_sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /var/www/store.spiritualselftransformation.com/libe_sqlite3.so)
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/libe_sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/www/store.spiritualselftransformation.com/e_sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/e_sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/www/store.spiritualselftransformation.com/libe_sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.4/libe_sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

There is indeed no e_sqlite3 in my folder but the libe_sqlite3.so file is there.
Wait a second... maybe that's the real error
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

EDIT: I restored csproj to the previous Git version and republished; that didn't fix it. Ended up restoring a server backup. Website came back online. Simply re-publishing with the non-modified project file is breaking the website... Using Jetbrains Rider. What could have gone wrong?
Publish to Folder profile set to net8.0, Release, linux-x64, delete existing files. Everything looks good in the publish.

Did you have to restore a server to bring a project online? So maybe the problem is how and what is updated in OS?

I restored backup and updated the server. That's fine. It's when I update that specific project that it fails so I kept a backup of old files this time.

After some research, I found the problem with ldd --version. Ubuntu 18LTS only ships with GLIBC 2.27; and some component now requires GLIBC 2.28. Unfortunately, it seems the only option is to upgrade the whole server

Note: 18.04 was out of standard support May 2023 - so unless you are in an extended support package it is probably time to upgrade your ubuntu server. Although it does seems more than unfortunate that a minor upgrade in .Net packages leads to this ...

Ya. I'm looking to migrate to state of the art: Vultr VPS with Docker apps, but that will take some time. I can migrate the websites one by one and gradually switch the DNS from old to new.
